# Error when clicking on a link that opens a pop up on moodle 3.5

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme, moodle-boost

I have updated my module from moodle 3.2 to moodle 3.5  and receive these errors in the debug web console:

**moodle-core-event: Global event published: FORM_ERROR**

yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js:5828 moodle-core-event:

**Global event published: BLOCK_CONTENT_UPDATED**

These errors show  when opening a pop up  with  atto editor so notes can be saved.  Unfortunately, I can't save the notes and it seems the above errors are causing the issue.

I have tracked down a similar error on the moodle forum site:

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=367647

However, no solution has been marked.  Sadly no apache errors are showing so I can't narrow down the problem.

Can someone shed some light on these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking the obvious, but did you purge the caches? Javascript is cached

Administration > Site administration > Development > Purge all caches

or

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

I always turn the cache off in `config.php` in a development environment `$CFG->cachejs = false;` but never on production, which has caught me out before.

Also, you might need to run grunt to minify the javascript files, then add the minified files to the git repository

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Grunt

If your javascript is in a folder called amd

```
grunt amd
```

If your javascript is in a folder called yui/src/something

```
grunt shifter
```

Or just

```
grunt js
```

Comment: Ok will give this a try.

Comment: Do I need to use grunt, can't I minify the JS another way ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only ever used grunt for Moodle/Totara